# Best low cost microcomputer for running Unity app + webcam

Tags: linux, arduino, webcam, microcontroller

I have an art installation I want to build that uses software written in Unity, implementing opencv and using a webcam, and displaying on some sort of inexpensive monitor. I can compile to Android/iOS/Linux. I was originally planning on using a raspberry pi, but Unity only compiles for the x86 architecture and I'd prefer not to use the android hack workarounds.

What's a good cheap microcomputer / microcontroller to use for this? Needs very little storage but ability to process realtime video with opencv. I don't need much storage. I saw the [Udoo x86](https://www.udoo.org/udoo-x86/), but ~$200 seems a bit expensive - was hoping to keep it around $50. Seems like intel maybe has some boards, like the [Quark](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/embedded/products/quark/mcu/d2000/overview.html), but I wasn't sure how it would perform with the video. Or maybe I could just run it off a cheap phone if I could figure out how to output to the monitor. Any hardware recommendations are appreciated.

Comment: You'll have to be more specific about your Unity user case scenario as rendering intensive 3D Unity projects will likely demand better hardware than can be provided at $200. I use OpenCV at work and it is pretty performative, and is capable of doing reasonable image capture on a IOT equipped Raspberry PI.

Comment: @BennettYeo - The application takes a webcam feed and overlays flat graphics or low poly models in realtime based on detected features with opencv. Are there other specifics are you looking for? The Udoo claims to be 10x faster than a raspberry pi.

Comment: If your Udoo claim is correct, this should be adequate given your webcam feed resolution is reasonable for the hardware. You could also consider purchasing a second-hand non-micro computer which may have better hardware.

Answer (score 1):

There are microcomputers I suggested in another similar question, and unless your cam needs a specific connector you can choose from those:

UP Core - https://up-shop.org/up-core/271-up-core.html 
1-4 GB RAM, 16-64 GB eMMC storage, Intel Atom X5 Z8350, 99$USD for cheapest options

ASUS Computer Stick VivoStick - https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16883221244 
2 GB RAM, 32 GB eMMC, Intel Atom X5 Z8350, 119$USD